# How is deSitter group tranformations different from poincare group transformations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, poincare-symmetry, de-sitter-spacetime

In QFT, we have studies Poincare group of massive and massless particles. Is the deSitter group also useful to study such things? What exactly is the main role of this group in QFT?

I just know the definition of the deSitter group. I was searching the internet to learn more about the deSitter group but everything I found was too advanced. So it would also be nice if references and resources are provided.